# create column in dataframe pandas, max between column and value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to create column in dataframe pandas, max between column and value

```
const = 10
df['new_val'] = max(df['val']-const, 0)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

input:

```
  val |
   12 |
   5  |
```

expected:

```
  val | new_val
   12 |   2
   5  |   0
```

Comment: how do you chose the row in which to assign the result? do you want a simple `df.loc[0, 'new_val'] = df['val'].max() - const`?

Comment: I want to do that for all rows.

Comment: How do you get 0? do you want `df['val'].sub(const).clip(lower=0)`?

Comment: I get 0 from max(-5,0)

Comment: Got it, then `df['val'].sub(const).clip(lower=0)` should work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `const` while ensuring not having negative numbers, [`subtract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['new_val'] = df['val'].sub(const).clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
   val  new_val
0   12        2
1    5        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) for `max` per column `val`:

```
const = 10
df['new_val'] = np.maximum(df['val'].sub(const), 0)
print (df)
   val  new_val
0   12        2
1    5        0
```

Or substract values with [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) for `0` for negative values:

```
const = 10
df['new_val'] = df['val'].sub(const).clip(lower=0)
print (df)
   val  new_val
0   12        2
1    5        0
```